# Over Extrusion Around Radius

Tags: extrusion

I have a Ender 3 S1 Pro, and I'm using PrusaSlicer to slice because it has some features I need that Cura doesn't have yet. The problem I'm running into is that when it goes round a bend it will over extrude once in a while. Straight line walls, it does great, but a radius sometimes messes up. Is there a setting I need to adjust for this? Here is a picture of what I mean. It does it a dozen or so times throughout the print. I print standing up like that.

[image: Over Extrusion]

Comment: Could the "over extrusion" possibly be the seam?

Comment: I don't think so, a z seam would just be a small spot, not the entire radius, right?